# Ayuda con formulas epplus (Excel) c#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, excel

Estoy realizando un excel en la cual realia unas fórmula, pero al momento de tomar una celda que es el resultado de una fórmula, para utilizarlo en otra fórmula este me muestra en la celda literalmente la fórmula.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como está remarcada en los colores amarillo es el rango de proveedores **L**, azul es la celda en la columna **O**, y en verde es el rango de que hay en la columna **K** que se llama MONTO

Éste es el código:

```
  string SUMA_SI_MONTO = celda + ":" + comparativo.Cells[(columna1 + i), (columna + 2)]; // K7:K8 MONTO

                string SUMA_SI_PROVEE = celda_Final + ":" + comparativo.Cells[(columna1 + i), (columna + 3)];// L7:L8 PROVEEDOR

                comparativo.Cells[(columna1 + i + 1), (columna + 2)].Formula = SUMA;// PRECIO AUTORIZADO
                for (int q = 0; q < proveedor.ToList().Count(); q++) {

                    // =SUMAR.SI(T7:T46,W7,S7:S46)
                    string _SUMA_SI = "=SUMAR.SI(" + SUMA_SI_PROVEE + "," + comparativo.Cells[(provedor_cont - 4) + q, (cont + 6)] +"," + SUMA_SI_MONTO + ")";
                    comparativo.Cells[(provedor_cont - 4) + q, (cont + 7)].Value = _SUMA_SI; // =SUMAR.SI(L7:L9,O10,K7:K9)

                }
```

Y al parecer solo me esta concatenando la fórmula. tengo que entrar en modo de edición de la celda y salir de esta para que me muestre el resultado.

¿Alguien que le haya sucedido lo mismo para ayudarme?
Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

ya pude resolverlo, al parecer siempre le indicaba a la celda como valor cuando debía ser como formula.

Como lo tengo.

```
comparativo.Cells[(provedor_cont - 4) + q, (cont + 7)].Value = "=SUM(B1:B3)";
```

Como debe de ser

```
comparativo.Cells[(provedor_cont - 4) + q, (cont + 7)].Formula = "=SUM(B1:B3)";
```

Gracias!